# Google Apps Script: How to get text from textArea? (replaceText)

Tags: google-apps-script, textarea

I need replace text in textArea, what am I doing wrong?

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var textArea = app.createTextArea()
  .setText('here is text... here is text... here is text...')
  .setName('theText').setId('theText')
  .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('processing'));
  app.add(textArea);
  return app;
}

function processing(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter.theText); // In Log I see: 'here is text... here is text... here is text...'
  var textIn = e.parameter.theText;
  var textOut = textIn.replaceText('/[text]/', 'new text'); // Here I get error: Unable to find a function replaseText in the object here is text... here is text... here is text....
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('theText').setText(textOut);
  return app;  
}
```

I tryed getText, getBody, editAsText etc. with 'e.parameter.theText' but with same result.
Where is mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` method is simply `replace` and not `replaceText`  this is pure [JavaScript.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)
It seems that you are making a confusion between [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/?hl=fr-FR) and Javascript string manipulation.